# Serializing json string without escaping quote in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a string variable that contains json of list of strings. And I want to add this as a value to a map for representing as string list value. To be more specific:

```
String jsonListString = "[\"A\", \"B\"]";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
map.put("KEY", jsonListString);


String serialized = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);
System.out.println("Example:" + serialized);
```

The output is the following:

```
Example:{"KEY":"[\"A\", \"B\"]"}
```

I'm expecting without escaping quotes

```
Example:{"KEY":["A", "B"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are assigning a string as the value to KEY. If you want to assign an array instead it needs to actually be an array.

Ex

```
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap();
map.put("KEY", new String[]{"A", "B"});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! BTW, I'm taking the json string as an input so is there a way to do this without needing to parse the input json?

Comment: If you were serializing an object that was annotatable you might be able to use @JsonRawValue. However, since you are serializing a map I am not sure if you can indicate to Jackson not to quote things.  Maybe you can use a mixin I am not sure.